# get table row data on checkbox check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Edit : I would like to rephrase my question

I am simple trying to get anchor tag text inside `<td>` on checkbox check.
Problem is that anchor tag doesn't have id or class

This is a sample of my table

```
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped users">

 <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:user">

  <tr id="user-18">
   <th scope="row" class="check-column">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="user_18">Select abc</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" id="user_18" class="subscriber" value="18">
   </th>


   <td class="username column-username has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Username">

    <a href="#">abc</a>
   </td>
</table>
```

I have searched some post and tried to create some function

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
 $('#changeit').click(function(){

        var values = [];
        $(".wp-list-table input[name='users[]']:checked").each(function(){
            row = $(this).closest("tr");

        });

        alert($(row).find("a")[0]);




    });

</script>
```

this gave me anchor tag href data, but I need text enclosed in anchor tag.

I tried

```
alert($(row).find("a")[0].text());
alert($(row).find("a")[0].val());
alert($(row).find("a")[0].val);
```

But they are not giving me the anchor tag text.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I guess you need quotation mark in name selector like `input[name='users[]']`

Comment: thanks , it helped me to get inside check event, but still I am not able to get the elements value inside <td> 's

Comment: in this `find("input[name=Username]")` again you are missing quotation and I can't see any input with name 'Username'. If you are sure it is able to store array, can you put a `console.log(values)` instead of multiple `alerts` ? and check browsers developer console ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function Bindthis() {
        $('#changeit').on('click', function() {
            alert('1'); //this is hitting
            var values = [];
            $('.subscriber').attr('checked', true).each(function() {
                alert('2');
                row = $(this).closest("tr");
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily traceable by following some *good coding practices*.

First, you need your code well indented. Indentation is a must if you want to write good, clean and error free code. Error free because indentation helps a lot to identify different scopes.

Second, ALWAYS look for logs. I know that you don't look for logs because you use `alert()` instead of `console.log()`, and also, if you open the console (F12) with your code, you will notice this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #the-list input[name=users[]]:checked
```

With this, is easy to understand that the selector syntax is wrong. Searching a bit around internet and learning about selectors, you will notice that the syntax needs some quotes, like this `#the-list input[name='users[]']:checked`.

Seems that you don't understand well how selectors work, so, to avoid this problem and future ones, I recommend you to read a bit about them. This way you will avoid repeating the same selectors questions here. Here is a good reference website, with an online tester: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: thanx  . i know the console use , but didnt know the single quote for users

Comment: @NeerajVerma Yeah, I saw your edit. Now you are selecting an "input" with a "name" attribute, but you have a "td" instead with "data-colname" attribute. If you don't really know what is happening, check my link to understand it better. Understanding selectors will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

finally I made this code which is working for me

```
 $(".wp-list-table input[name='users[]']:checked").each(function(){
            row = $(this).closest("tr");
            anchor  = $(this).closest('tr').find("a:first");


        });
        alert($(anchor).text());
```